# Java or Solaris issue

Tags: java, oracle, solaris

so i have been tasked with migrating some machines mainly all windows and all has gone well until now with one machine giving us this error.

As i am no software techie type and have never used Solaris or java for apps its puzzled me and I am wondering if its the VM side settings/flags? is it set to the correct settings which allows it to run and the next leads to memory  allocation,  which could be down to versioning of the system/software. Now the fun part a bit of guessing. is it going to be a setting in the config files that it doesn’t like, and am looking at it from a bluescreen type issue

This message is from the new zone copy  the old one is a Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7 version I think

If any one can help I will buy you a coffee or a pint

````
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xfc0b7638, pid=81, tid=2
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_75-b13) (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.75-b04 mixed mode solaris-sparc )
# Problematic frame:
# J 57 C1 java.util.HashMap.getEntry(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry; (86 bytes) @ 0xfc0b7638 [0xfc0b75a0+0x98]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/boxarr_domain/core or core.81
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0002a000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=2, stack(0xfe110000,0xfe190000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x722e6374

Registers:
G1=0xebd2ef28 G2=0x0002a000 G3=0xffffa000 G4=0xebd2ef28
G5=0xebc05038 G6=0x00000000 G7=0xfe0f0200 Y=0x00000000
O0=0x00000200 O1=0xe162ba08 O2=0x00000008 O3=0xacb08128
O4=0x00000001 O5=0x00000001 O6=0xfe18d530 O7=0xfc0b75f4
L0=0x8ba4b808 L1=0xff1f8000 L2=0x0000000a L3=0x00002000
L4=0x00000001 L5=0xacaf889a L6=0xacaf9bc0 L7=0x00000000
I0=0x722e636c I1=0xacb0a860 I2=0x00000006 I3=0x00000072
I4=0xb08e9330 I5=0x00000005 I6=0xfe18d5d8 I7=0xfc0c745c
PC=0xfc0b7638 nPC=0xfc0b763c


Top of Stack: (sp=0xfe18d530)
0xfe18d530:   8ba4b808 ff1f8000 0000000a 00002000
0xfe18d540:   00000001 acaf889a acaf9bc0 00000000
0xfe18d550:   722e636c acb0a860 00000006 00000072
0xfe18d560:   b08e9330 00000005 fe18d5d8 fc0c745c
0xfe18d570:   fe18d5e8 fc141900 acac5898 000a8400
0xfe18d580:   fedce888 fe18dbd9 00002000 00000000
0xfe18d590:   00002000 acaf7b98 0000000d 00000000
0xfe18d5a0:   b0a10198 acac58b8 b0afe518 acac5908

Instructions: (pc=0xfc0b7638)
0xfc0b7618:   80 a2 00 0a 08 40 00 30 01 00 00 00 d2 02 e0 0c
0xfc0b7628:   b0 10 00 09 80 a6 20 00 02 40 00 1f 01 00 00 00
0xfc0b7638:   d2 06 20 08 80 a2 40 10 12 40 00 12 01 00 00 00
0xfc0b7648:   d2 06 20 0c 80 a2 40 19 02 40 00 13 01 00 00 00

Register to memory mapping:

G1=0xebd2ef28 is an oop
{instance class}
- klass: {other class}
G2=0x0002a000 is a thread
G3=0xffffa000 is an unknown value
G4=0xebd2ef28 is an oop
{instance class}
- klass: {other class}
G5=0xebc05038 is an oop
{method}
- klass: {other class}
G6=0x00000000 is an unknown value
G7=0xfe0f0200 is an unknown value

O0=0x00000200 is an unknown value
O1=0xe162ba08 is an unallocated location in the heap
O2=0x00000008 is an unknown value
O3=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb]

Stack: [0xfe110000,0xfe190000],  sp=0xfe18d530,  free space=501k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 57 C1 java.util.HashMap.getEntry(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry; (86 bytes) @ 0xfc0b7638 [0xfc0b75a0+0x98]
J 109 C1 java.util.HashMap.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (29 bytes) @ 0xfc0c7464 [0xfc0c7420+0x44]
J 257 C1 java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V (328 bytes) @ 0xfc0fca40 [0xfc0fc600+0x440]
J 494 C1 java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference()Ljava/util/jar/Manifest; (113 bytes) @ 0xfc15024c [0xfc14ffa0+0x2ac]
J 512 C1 java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest()Ljava/util/jar/Manifest; (5 bytes) @ 0xfc1582f4 [0xfc1582c0+0x34]
J 570 C1 sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest()Ljava/util/jar/Manifest; (11 bytes) @ 0xfc170788 [0xfc170740+0x48]
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+34
J 466 C1 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Class; (73 bytes) @ 0xfc1462d8 [0xfc146240+0x98]
J 465 C1 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0xfc145fb4 [0xfc145f80+0x34]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x12b124]  void JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*,methodHandle*,JavaCallArguments*,Thread*)+0x320
V  [libjvm.so+0x136328]  JVM_DoPrivileged+0xe80
C  [libjava.so+0xe160]  Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedExceptionAction_2Ljava_security_AccessControlContext_2+0x1c
J 464  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0xfc1457b8 [0xfc1456e0+0xd8]
J 462 C1 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (29 bytes) @ 0xfc145a64 [0xfc1459e0+0x84]
J 346 C1 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; (122 bytes) @ 0xfc116a00 [0xfc1167a0+0x260]
J 515 C1 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (7 bytes) @ 0xfc1588cc [0xfc158880+0x4c]
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ClassLoadingUtils.loadNonArrayClass(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;+15
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;+38
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingType.getJavaClass(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/BindingType;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;+15
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingType.<init>(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/BindingType;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/TypeMarshaller;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/TypeUnmarshaller;)V+18
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingType.<init>(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/BindingType;)V+4
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeRuntimeBindingType.<init>(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/BindingType;)V+2
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameRuntimeBindingType.<init>(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/ByNameBean;)V+2
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingTypeTable$FactoryTypeVisitor.visit(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/ByNameBean;)V+6
j  com.bea.staxb.buildtime.internal.bts.ByNameBean.accept(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/BindingTypeVisitor;)V+2
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingTypeTable.allocateType(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/BindingType;)Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingType;+5
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingTypeTable.createRuntimeType(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/BindingType;Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/BindingLoader;)Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingType;+63
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.getRuntimeType(Lcom/bea/staxb/buildtime/internal/bts/BindingType;)Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingType;+9
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingType.determineActualRuntimeType(Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/UnmarshalResult;)Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingType;+32
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.extractAndFillElementProp(Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingProperty;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+39
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameUnmarshaller.deserializeContents(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/UnmarshalResult;)V+104
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeUnmarshaller.unmarshalIntoIntermediary(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/UnmarshalResult;)V+9
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.unmarshalElementProperty(Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingProperty;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingType;)Ljava/lang/Object;+61
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.extractAndFillElementProp(Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingProperty;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+49
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameUnmarshaller.deserializeContents(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/UnmarshalResult;)V+104
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeUnmarshaller.unmarshalIntoIntermediary(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/UnmarshalResult;)V+9
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.unmarshalElementProperty(Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingProperty;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingType;)Ljava/lang/Object;+61
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.extractAndFillElementProp(Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingProperty;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+49
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameUnmarshaller.deserializeContents(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/UnmarshalResult;)V+104
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeUnmarshaller.unmarshalIntoIntermediary(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/UnmarshalResult;)V+9
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalBindingType(Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/internal/RuntimeBindingType;)Ljava/lang/Object;+121
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;)Ljava/lang/Object;+24
j  com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/UnmarshalOptions;)Ljava/lang/Object;+23
j  weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/bea/staxb/runtime/ObjectFactory;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+93
j  weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/util/List;Z)Lweblogic/descriptor/Descriptor;+135
j  weblogic.management.provider.internal.DescriptorManagerHelper.loadDescriptor(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lweblogic/management/provider/internal/DescriptorManagerHelperContext;)Lweblogic/descriptor/Descriptor;+76
j  weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl$IOHelperImpl.parseXML(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/lang/Object;+73
j  weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.parseNewStyleConfig()Lweblogic/management/configuration/DomainMBean;+471
j  weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl.<init>()V+59
j  weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService.start()V+11
j  weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(Lweblogic/server/ServerService;J)V+18
j  weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState()V+402
j  weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby()V+7
j  weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup()V+306
j  weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+71
j  weblogic.Server.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+49
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x12b124]  void JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*,methodHandle*,JavaCallArguments*,Thread*)+0x320
V  [libjvm.so+0x1a4990]  jni_CallStaticVoidMethod+0x684
C  [libjli.so+0x1f88]  JavaMain+0x748


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00aff800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10, stack(0xaa450000,0xaa4d0000)]
  0x0013e400 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8, stack(0xab580000,0xab600000)]
  0x0013b400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7, stack(0xab610000,0xab690000)]
  0x00139c00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6, stack(0xab6a0000,0xab720000)]
  0x00127400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5, stack(0xab730000,0xab7b0000)]
  0x00122400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4, stack(0xab7c0000,0xab840000)]
=>0x0002a000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=2, stack(0xfe110000,0xfe190000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0011ec00 VMThread [stack: 0xab850000,0xab8d0000] [id=3]
  0x00151800 WatcherThread [stack: 0xab4f0000,0xab570000] [id=9]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
def new generation   total 78656K, used 24121K [0xabc00000, 0xb1150000, 0xc1150000)
  eden space 69952K,  22% used [0xabc00000, 0xacb0e6e0, 0xb0050000)
  from space 8704K, 100% used [0xb08d0000, 0xb1150000, 0xb1150000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0xb0050000, 0xb0050000, 0xb08d0000)
tenured generation   total 174784K, used 1579K [0xc1150000, 0xcbc00000, 0xebc00000)
   the space 174784K,   0% used [0xc1150000, 0xc12daef0, 0xc12db000, 0xcbc00000)
compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 8271K [0xebc00000, 0xec800000, 0xfbc00000)
   the space 12288K,  67% used [0xebc00000, 0xec413cf0, 0xec413e00, 0xec800000)
No shared spaces configured.

Card table byte_map: [0xfbce0000,0xfbf62000] byte_map_base: 0xfb782000

Polling page: 0xff1f8000

Code Cache  [0xfc000000, 0xfc188000, 0xfe000000)
total_blobs=748 nmethods=600 adapters=86 free_code_cache=31220Kb largest_free_block=31969408

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1.126 Thread 0x0013b400  600   !         weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.ScannerState::read (321 bytes)
Event: 1.127 Thread 0x0013b400 nmethod 600 0xfc178cc8 code [0xfc178f00, 0xfc1795d8]
Event: 1.127 Thread 0x0013b400  601   !         weblogic.xml.babel.reader.XmlReader$Utf8Reader::read (786 bytes)
Event: 1.129 Thread 0x0013b400 nmethod 601 0xfc179e48 code [0xfc17a160, 0xfc17af90]
Event: 1.140 Thread 0x0013b400  602 %           com.bea.xbean.common.XMLChar::<clinit> @ 4333 (4917 bytes)
Event: 1.155 Thread 0x0013b400 nmethod 602% 0xfc17bfc8 code [0xfc17c340, 0xfc17ef54]
Event: 1.171 Thread 0x0013b400  603   !         java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream::readBlockHeader (249 bytes)
Event: 1.172 Thread 0x0013b400 nmethod 603 0xfc181448 code [0xfc181720, 0xfc182008]
Event: 1.172 Thread 0x0013b400  604             java.io.ObjectInputStream::access$500 (5 bytes)
Event: 1.172 Thread 0x0013b400 nmethod 604 0xfc182d88 code [0xfc182e60, 0xfc182ef4]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 0.897 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
def new generation   total 78656K, used 69952K [0xabc00000, 0xb1150000, 0xc1150000)
  eden space 69952K, 100% used [0xabc00000, 0xb0050000, 0xb0050000)
  from space 8704K,   0% used [0xb0050000, 0xb0050000, 0xb08d0000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0xb08d0000, 0xb08d0000, 0xb1150000)
tenured generation   total 174784K, used 0K [0xc1150000, 0xcbc00000, 0xebc00000)
   the space 174784K,   0% used [0xc1150000, 0xc1150000, 0xc1150200, 0xcbc00000)
compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 6389K [0xebc00000, 0xec800000, 0xfbc00000)
   the space 12288K,  51% used [0xebc00000, 0xec23d568, 0xec23d600, 0xec800000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 0.939 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
def new generation   total 78656K, used 8704K [0xabc00000, 0xb1150000, 0xc1150000)
  eden space 69952K,   0% used [0xabc00000, 0xabc00000, 0xb0050000)
  from space 8704K, 100% used [0xb08d0000, 0xb1150000, 0xb1150000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0xb0050000, 0xb0050000, 0xb08d0000)
tenured generation   total 174784K, used 1579K [0xc1150000, 0xcbc00000, 0xebc00000)
   the space 174784K,   0% used [0xc1150000, 0xc12daef0, 0xc12db000, 0xcbc00000)
compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 6389K [0xebc00000, 0xec800000, 0xfbc00000)
   the space 12288K,  51% used [0xebc00000, 0xec23d568, 0xec23d600, 0xec800000)
No shared spaces configured.
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 1.125 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xac9b4f78 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281
Event: 1.125 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xac9c03a0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281
Event: 1.126 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xac9c4b00 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281
Event: 1.126 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xac9caff0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281
Event: 1.127 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xac9d0330 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281
Event: 1.127 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xac9d6db8 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281
Event: 1.165 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xac9f5cf0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281
Event: 1.180 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xaca9b150 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281
Event: 1.181 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xacac1f18 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281
Event: 1.181 Thread 0x0002a000 Threw 0xacac3430 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-sparc/jdk7u75/1940/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1281

Events (10 events):
Event: 1.127 loading class 0x00e11c18
Event: 1.127 loading class 0x00e11c18 done
Event: 1.127 loading class 0x00d121b0
Event: 1.127 loading class 0x00d121b0 done
Event: 1.165 loading class 0x00d9a6b0
Event: 1.165 loading class 0x00d9a6b0 done
Event: 1.166 loading class 0x00ad5de0
Event: 1.166 loading class 0x00ad5de0 done
Event: 1.180 loading class 0x00e18030
Event: 1.180 loading class 0x00e18030 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00010000      /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java
0xff170000      /lib/libthread.so.1
0xff130000      /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/../lib/sparc/jli/libjli.so
0xff110000      /lib/libdl.so.1
0xfefb0000      /lib/libc.so.1
0xff150000      /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1
0xfe400000      /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/sparc/client/libjvm.so
0xfef60000      /lib/libsocket.so.1
0xfef80000      /usr/lib/libsched.so.1
0xfef40000      /lib/libm.so.1
0xfef10000      /usr/lib/libCrun.so.1
0xfeef0000      /lib/libdoor.so.1
0xfeeb0000      /usr/lib/libdemangle.so.1
0xfee90000      /lib/libkstat.so.1
0xfe340000      /lib/libnsl.so.1
0xfe290000      /lib/libm.so.2
0xfee50000      /lib/libmp.so.2
0xfee20000      /lib/libmd.so.1
0xfe270000      /platform/sun4v/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
0xfe240000      /lib/libscf.so.1
0xfe220000      /lib/libuutil.so.1
0xfe200000      /lib/libgen.so.1
0xfe0d0000      /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/sparc/libverify.so
0xfe090000      /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/sparc/libjava.so
0xfe030000      /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/sparc/libzip.so
0xaa570000      /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/sparc/libnet.so
0xaa540000      /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/sparc/libnio.so
0xaa520000      /lib/librt.so.1
0xaa500000      /lib/libsendfile.so.1
0xaa4e0000      /lib/libaio.so.1

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Xverify:none -da -Dplatform.home=/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3 -Dwls.home=/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.home=/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.management.discover=true -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath -Dlog4j.configuration=boxarrlog4j.properties -Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources=esapi -Dboxarr.ejb.jndi=ejb.boxarrDataRemoteBean#com.boxarr.api.transfer.client.ejb.BoxarrDataRemote -Dboxarr.ejb.web.jndi=ejb.boxarrWebUtilsBean#com.boxarr.api.transfer.web.ejb.BoxarrWebUtils -Dboxarr.rest.security.https.enabled=false -Dboxarr.rest.security.https.port=7002 -Dboxarr.rest.security.http.port=7001 -Dboxarr.ejb.jms.destination=./BoxarrJMSModule!boxarrTopic
java_command: weblogic.Server
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75
CLASSPATH=/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/lib/tools.jar:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.6.0.jar:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/xqrl.jar:/opt/java:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/boxarr_domain/boxarr/config
PATH=/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/bin:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/bin:/opt/java/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/VRTSvcs/bin:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/bin:.
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/native:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/native:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/native/solaris/sparc:/boxarr/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/native/solaris/sparc/oci920_8
SHELL=/bin/csh

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x7f16f0], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x7f16f0], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x1e225c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x1e225c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x1e225c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x1e225c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x6af81c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIGHUP: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x6af81c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x6af81c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIG39: [libjvm.so+0x6b45e4], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000008
SIG40: [libjvm.so+0x1e225c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:                   Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10s_u11wos_24a SPARC
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 17 January 2013

uname:SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-59 sun4v
  (T2 libthread)
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
load average:0.01 0.02 0.02

CPU:total 8 v9, popc, vis1, vis2, vis3, blk_init, cbcond, sun4v, niagara_plus

Memory: 8k page, physical 16777216k(16465856k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.75-b04) for solaris-sparc JRE (1.7.0_75-b13), built on Dec 19 2014 01:36:36 by "java_re" with Sun Studio 12u1

time: Thu Sep  3 11:13:42 2020
elapsed time: 1 seconds```
````

Comment: [Best way on how to solve/debug JVM crash (SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109313/best-way-on-how-to-solve-debug-jvm-crash-sigsegv) might have some useful steps for you

Comment: cheers will review

Comment: Is your Solaris system fully patched and up-to-date?  Java 1.7.0_75 is from 2015. If you've installed something newer than that, there could very well be incompatibilities.  And if this is an outside-facing web server, you'd best upgrade that system.  If you don't have a support contract with Oracle, you **really** need to get off Java 1.7 as public support ended in 2015 and running a public-facing web server with an unupdated JDK that old is professionally reckless because if anyone thinks you're important, they're going to root your server real quick.

Comment: Hi Andy luckily it isnt a public facing system its air gaped but due to its nature the business wont upgrade i believe they have tried and it failed. but it is some thing to ask the team that look after it cheers