# Java crash on pycharm startup Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, crash

When opening a project in Pycharm Community (latest version as of now), it crashes immediately.

When opening again, it lets me see the log from last time:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9424fca4ea, pid=6033, tid=6124
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-11.0.10.9-1341.35-dcevm (11.0.10+9) (build 11.0.10+9-b1341.35)
# Java VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM JBR-11.0.10.9-1341.35-dcevm (11.0.10+9-b1341.35, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 18786 c2 com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (12 bytes) @ 0x00007f9424fca4ea [0x00007f9424fc9200+0x00000000000012ea]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or dumping to /home/epdadmin/core.6033)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -XX:ErrorFile=/home/epdadmin/java_error_in_pycharm_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/epdadmin/java_error_in_pycharm_.hprof -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains -Didea.paths.selector=PyCharmCE2021.1 -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/epdadmin/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/pycharm64.vmoptions -Didea.platform.prefix=PyCharmCore com.intellij.idea.Main

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10980XE CPU @ 3.00GHz, 36 cores, 125G, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Time: Mon Apr 12 16:49:39 2021 IDT elapsed time: 34.405546 seconds (0d 0h 0m 34s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f9344091000):  JavaThread "Indexing" [_thread_in_Java, id=6124, stack(0x00007f928aaa1000,0x00007f928aba2000)]

Stack: [0x00007f928aaa1000,0x00007f928aba2000],  sp=0x00007f928ab9d010,  free space=1008k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 18786 c2 com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (12 bytes) @ 0x00007f9424fca4ea [0x00007f9424fc9200+0x00000000000012ea]
J 18916 c2 com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.forward.PersistentMapBasedForwardIndex.put(Ljava/lang/Integer;Lcom/intellij/openapi/util/io/ByteArraySequence;)V (37 bytes) @ 0x00007f9424d9ed10 [0x00007f9424d9ecc0+0x0000000000000050]
J 20747 c1 com.intellij.util.indexing.snapshot.SnapshotInputMappings.savePersistentData(Ljava/util/Map;I)Z (55 bytes) @ 0x00007f94201548cc [0x00007f9420154720+0x00000000000001ac]
J 20746 c1 com.intellij.util.indexing.snapshot.SnapshotInputMappings.putData(Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/FileContent;Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/impl/InputData;)Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/impl/InputData; (138 bytes) @ 0x00007f9420154094 [0x00007f9420153da0+0x00000000000002f4]
J 21433 c2 com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.storage.VfsAwareMapReduceIndex.mapInput(ILjava/lang/Object;)Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/impl/InputData; (10 bytes) @ 0x00007f94251eaaf8 [0x00007f94251ea6e0+0x0000000000000418]
J 21526 c2 com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.mapInputAndPrepareUpdate(ILjava/lang/Object;)Lcom/intellij/openapi/util/Computable; (85 bytes) @ 0x00007f94252947a4 [0x00007f9425294760+0x0000000000000044]
J 23149 c1 com.intellij.indexing.composite.CompositeInvertedIndexBase.mapInputAndPrepareUpdate(ILcom/intellij/util/indexing/FileContent;)Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/IndexInfrastructureExtensionUpdateComputation; (102 bytes) @ 0x00007f941f0db19c [0x00007f941f0da000+0x000000000000119c]
J 23096 c1 com.intellij.indexing.composite.CompositeInvertedIndexBase.mapInputAndPrepareUpdate(ILjava/lang/Object;)Lcom/intellij/openapi/util/Computable; (10 bytes) @ 0x00007f941e708364 [0x00007f941e7081e0+0x0000000000000184]
J 17897 c2 com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.updateSingleIndex(Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/ID;Lcom/intellij/openapi/vfs/VirtualFile;ILcom/intellij/util/indexing/FileContent;)Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/FileBasedIndexImpl$SingleIndexUpdateStats; (367 bytes) @ 0x00007f942589800c [0x00007f9425897ca0+0x000000000000036c]
J 21203 c1 com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.lambda$doIndexFileContent$23(Lcom/intellij/openapi/vfs/VirtualFile;Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/IndexedFileImpl;Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/contentQueue/CachedFileContent;Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;Lcom/intellij/openapi/util/Ref;Lcom/intellij/openapi/util/Ref;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Set;Lcom/intellij/openapi/util/Ref;Ljava/util/Map;)V (437 bytes) @ 0x00007f942022bcdc [0x00007f942022b680+0x000000000000065c]
J 22562 c1 com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl$$Lambda$2260.run()V (48 bytes) @ 0x00007f942039093c [0x00007f9420390840+0x00000000000000fc]
J 17596 c1 com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.freezeFileTypeTemporarilyIn(Lcom/intellij/openapi/vfs/VirtualFile;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V (189 bytes) @ 0x00007f941e677c84 [0x00007f941e676e40+0x0000000000000e44]
J 21587 c1 com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.doIndexFileContent(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/contentQueue/CachedFileContent;)Lcom/intellij/openapi/util/Pair; (184 bytes) @ 0x00007f941e74f3e4 [0x00007f941e74d8a0+0x0000000000001b44]
J 21585 c1 com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.indexFileContent(Lcom/intellij/openapi/project/Project;Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/contentQueue/CachedFileContent;)Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/diagnostic/FileIndexingStatistics; (237 bytes) @ 0x00007f941e72f624 [0x00007f941e72e560+0x00000000000010c4]
J 21583 c1 com.intellij.util.indexing.contentQueue.IndexUpdateRunner$$Lambda$2259.call()Ljava/lang/Object; (16 bytes) @ 0x00007f941e3bdf3c [0x00007f941e3bde60+0x00000000000000dc]
J 21885 c1 com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.insideReadAction(Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;Lcom/intellij/openapi/util/Ref;)V (115 bytes) @ 0x00007f941e9561ec [0x00007f941e955c80+0x000000000000056c]
J 21883 c1 com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission$$Lambda$1278.run()V (16 bytes) @ 0x00007f941e95a42c [0x00007f941e95a360+0x00000000000000cc]
J 21048 c1 com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Z (60 bytes) @ 0x00007f94201ecdac [0x00007f94201ecac0+0x00000000000002ec]
J 21039 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils$$Lambda$1090.run()V (12 bytes) @ 0x00007f94201e9334 [0x00007f94201e9260+0x00000000000000d4]
J 21025 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runActionAndCancelBeforeWrite(Lcom/intellij/openapi/application/ex/ApplicationEx;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Z (114 bytes) @ 0x00007f94201dd144 [0x00007f94201dca80+0x00000000000006c4]
J 21023 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils$$Lambda$1093.compute()Ljava/lang/Object; (16 bytes) @ 0x00007f94201d9234 [0x00007f94201d91c0+0x0000000000000074]
J 19177 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager$$Lambda$870.run()V (12 bytes) @ 0x00007f941ef1d1b4 [0x00007f941ef1d140+0x0000000000000074]
J 13885 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V (118 bytes) @ 0x00007f941f9bc324 [0x00007f941f9bc040+0x00000000000002e4]
J 13884 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$$Lambda$437.run()V (12 bytes) @ 0x00007f941f9bb3c4 [0x00007f941f9bb340+0x0000000000000084]
J 22719 c2 com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;Ljava/lang/Thread;Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V (606 bytes) @ 0x00007f9425316ca4 [0x00007f9425316aa0+0x0000000000000204]
J 13239 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;)V (138 bytes) @ 0x00007f941f7fbc7c [0x00007f941f7fb5a0+0x00000000000006dc]
J 13238 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;)V (79 bytes) @ 0x00007f941f7fd2c4 [0x00007f941f7fc980+0x0000000000000944]
J 13936 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;)V (29 bytes) @ 0x00007f941f9d1304 [0x00007f941f9d0d40+0x00000000000005c4]
J 20895 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runWithWriteActionPriority(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;)Z (86 bytes) @ 0x00007f94201b370c [0x00007f94201b3220+0x00000000000004ec]
J 20912 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runInReadActionWithWriteActionPriority(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;)Z (62 bytes) @ 0x00007f94201bd6bc [0x00007f94201bcf00+0x00000000000007bc]
J 21287 c1 com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.attemptComputation()Z (191 bytes) @ 0x00007f9420264fa4 [0x00007f9420264080+0x0000000000000f24]
J 21540 c1 com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.executeSynchronously()Ljava/lang/Object; (91 bytes) @ 0x00007f941e5aa264 [0x00007f941e5aa1e0+0x0000000000000084]
J 21539 c1 com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl.executeSynchronously()Ljava/lang/Object; (75 bytes) @ 0x00007f941e1100c4 [0x00007f941e10fcc0+0x0000000000000404]
J 22602 c1 com.intellij.util.indexing.contentQueue.IndexUpdateRunner.indexOneFileOfJob(Lcom/intellij/util/indexing/contentQueue/IndexUpdateRunner$IndexingJob;)V (322 bytes) @ 0x00007f94203ae634 [0x00007f94203ad8e0+0x0000000000000d54]
J 22600 c1 com.intellij.util.indexing.contentQueue.IndexUpdateRunner$$Lambda$2240.run()V (12 bytes) @ 0x00007f94203a2a24 [0x00007f94203a2960+0x00000000000000c4]
J 22597 c1 com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressSuspender.executeNonSuspendableSection(Lcom/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressIndicator;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V (77 bytes) @ 0x00007f94203a106c [0x00007f94203a0c80+0x00000000000003ec]
j  com.intellij.util.indexing.contentQueue.IndexUpdateRunner.indexJobsFairly()V+144
j  com.intellij.util.indexing.contentQueue.IndexUpdateRunner.lambda$doIndexFiles$0(Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger;)V+1
j  com.intellij.util.indexing.contentQueue.IndexUpdateRunner$$Lambda$2239.run()V+8
J 11660 c1 com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute()V (40 bytes) @ 0x00007f941f35cd94 [0x00007f941f35ca80+0x0000000000000314]
j  com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1$$Lambda$491.run()V+4
J 16649 c1 com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V (74 bytes) @ 0x00007f941fdbacc4 [0x00007f941fdbaa40+0x0000000000000284]
J 11661 c1 com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run()V (76 bytes) @ 0x00007f941f36a564 [0x00007f941f369b00+0x0000000000000a64]
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+92 java.base@11.0.10
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5 java.base@11.0.10
j  java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+23 java.base@11.0.10
j  java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1 java.base@11.0.10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x86f381]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle const&, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x331
V  [libjvm.so+0x91a03a]  JVM_DoPrivileged+0x52a
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 java.base@11.0.10
j  java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run()V+15 java.base@11.0.10
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 java.base@11.0.10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x86f381]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle const&, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x331
V  [libjvm.so+0x86d600]  JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Klass*, Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x160
V  [libjvm.so+0x86d6d1]  JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle, Klass*, Symbol*, Symbol*, Thread*)+0x81
V  [libjvm.so+0x90d76c]  thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*)+0x6c
V  [libjvm.so+0xe087f0]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0xd0
V  [libjvm.so+0xe04609]  Thread::call_run()+0x149
V  [libjvm.so+0xbc66ae]  thread_native_entry(Thread*)+0xee


siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000009

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007f928ab9d070 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f9344091000
RBX=0x0 is NULL
RCX=654583554 is a compressed pointer to object: com.intellij.util.io.DirectBufferWrapper
{0x0000000138213810} - klass: 'com/intellij/util/io/DirectBufferWrapper'
RDX=0x0 is NULL
RSP=0x00007f928ab9d010 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f9344091000
RBP=0x0 is NULL
RSI=0x0000000086915530 is an oop: com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage
{0x0000000086915530} - klass: 'com/intellij/util/io/PagedFileStorage'
RDI=0x0000000056080000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0 is NULL
R9 =279331733 is a compressed pointer to object: com.intellij.util.io.StorageLockContext
{0x0000000085321ca8} - klass: 'com/intellij/util/io/StorageLockContext'
R10=0x0000000000000009 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000869152d0 is an oop: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator
{0x00000000869152d0} - klass: 'com/intellij/util/io/PersistentBTreeEnumerator'
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13=279331741 is a compressed pointer to object: java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync
{0x0000000085321ce8} - klass: 'java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync'
R14=0x0 is NULL
R15=0x00007f9344091000 is a thread


Registers:
RAX=0x00007f928ab9d070, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000027042702, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00007f928ab9d010, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x0000000086915530, RDI=0x0000000056080000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000010a64395, R10=0x0000000000000009, R11=0x00000000869152d0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000010a6439d, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x00007f9344091000
RIP=0x00007f9424fca4ea, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f928ab9d010)
0x00007f928ab9d010:   00000000869152d0 00000000869152d0
0x00007f928ab9d020:   0000000086914df0 0000000000000000
0x00007f928ab9d030:   000005005639b0d8 0000000010d22a5a
0x00007f928ab9d040:   0000000110d22a5a 00000000869152d0

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f9424fca4ea)
0x00007f9424fca3ea:   f0 ff ff 48 89 03 e9 13 00 00 00 4c 8b d0 48 33
0x00007f9424fca3fa:   c0 f0 4d 0f b1 7a 7e 48 c7 03 03 00 00 00 0f 84
0x00007f9424fca40a:   be ee ff ff 49 8b f3 48 8d 54 24 60 48 8b 6c 24
0x00007f9424fca41a:   28 4c 89 5c 24 18 4c 89 5c 24 40 66 90 e8 d4 48
0x00007f9424fca42a:   10 f8 4c 8b 5c 24 18 e9 96 ee ff ff 49 f7 c1 07
0x00007f9424fca43a:   00 00 00 0f 85 79 ff ff ff 49 f7 c1 00 03 00 00
0x00007f9424fca44a:   75 0d 48 81 e0 7f 03 00 00 4c 8b c0 4d 0b c7 f0
0x00007f9424fca45a:   4d 0f b1 03 75 ae e9 67 ee ff ff 48 8d 44 24 60
0x00007f9424fca46a:   48 81 38 00 00 00 00 0f 84 78 00 00 00 4d 8b 13
0x00007f9424fca47a:   49 f7 c2 02 00 00 00 74 64 48 33 c0 49 0b 82 8e
0x00007f9424fca48a:   00 00 00 75 60 49 8b 82 9e 00 00 00 49 0b 82 96
0x00007f9424fca49a:   00 00 00 75 0a 49 c7 42 7e 00 00 00 00 eb 46 49
0x00007f9424fca4aa:   81 ba a6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 74 25 48 33 c0 49
0x00007f9424fca4ba:   c7 42 7e 00 00 00 00 f0 83 04 24 00 49 81 ba a6
0x00007f9424fca4ca:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 75 0d f0 4d 0f b1 7a 7e 75
0x00007f9424fca4da:   05 83 c8 01 eb 0f a9 00 00 00 00 eb 08 4c 8b 10
0x00007f9424fca4ea:   f0 4d 0f b1 13 0f 84 db f5 ff ff 49 8b fb 48 8d
0x00007f9424fca4fa:   74 24 60 49 8b d7 49 ba 60 4e 49 35 94 7f 00 00
0x00007f9424fca50a:   41 ff d2 e9 be f5 ff ff be de ff ff ff 48 ff 74
0x00007f9424fca51a:   24 28 48 8f 44 24 08 4c 8b 5c 24 20 4c 89 5c 24
0x00007f9424fca52a:   10 4c 89 74 24 20 44 89 54 24 28 66 90 e8 c4 8b
0x00007f9424fca53a:   01 f8 be 4d ff ff ff 44 89 6c 24 0c 90 e8 b4 8b
0x00007f9424fca54a:   01 f8 be 4d ff ff ff 66 90 e8 a8 8b 01 f8 be e4
0x00007f9424fca55a:   ff ff ff 44 8b 44 24 30 44 89 44 24 04 48 ff 74
0x00007f9424fca56a:   24 28 48 8f 44 24 08 4c 8b 5c 24 20 4c 89 5c 24
0x00007f9424fca57a:   10 4c 8b 5c 24 38 4c 89 5c 24 18 4c 89 74 24 20
0x00007f9424fca58a:   44 89 6c 24 30 4c 89 4c 24 38 44 89 54 24 40 89
0x00007f9424fca59a:   4c 24 44 66 90 e8 5c 8b 01 f8 48 89 1c 24 4d 8b
0x00007f9424fca5aa:   eb 49 8b f7 49 ba f0 0e f6 34 94 7f 00 00 41 ff
0x00007f9424fca5ba:   d2 48 8b 1c 24 4d 8b dd e9 5f ef ff ff 49 8b d8
0x00007f9424fca5ca:   49 8b f7 49 ba f0 0e f6 34 94 7f 00 00 41 ff d2
0x00007f9424fca5da:   4c 8b c3 e9 5b f0 ff ff be 4d ff ff ff 48 8b 6c


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x00000000869152d0 is an oop: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator
{0x00000000869152d0} - klass: 'com/intellij/util/io/PersistentBTreeEnumerator'
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x00000000869152d0 is an oop: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator
{0x00000000869152d0} - klass: 'com/intellij/util/io/PersistentBTreeEnumerator'
stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x0000000086914df0 is an oop: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentMapImpl
{0x0000000086914df0} - klass: 'com/intellij/util/io/PersistentMapImpl'
stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x000005005639b0d8 is an unknown value
stack at sp + 5 slots: 282208858 is a compressed pointer to object: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator
{0x00000000869152d0} - klass: 'com/intellij/util/io/PersistentBTreeEnumerator'
stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x0000000110d22a5a is an unallocated location in the heap
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x00000000869152d0 is an oop: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator
{0x00000000869152d0} - klass: 'com/intellij/util/io/PersistentBTreeEnumerator'
```

---

> $ java -version

```
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

---

Will provide additional required information...

**How to make Pycharm not crash?**

---

Edit:

versions (in help>about) [notice the strange color theme mixup as well]:

[image]

Comment: @ThomasWeller I think so because it looks the same to me. It may not be the same. Not report a bug because it looks like there is one already. I don't know how to search their system. Also, I am not here to do QA for JetBrains. I need it to work. Moreover, it doesn't look like they solve bugs so fast. So that's why not.

Comment: For one, the bug I linked to (which I agree is unrelated) was opened in May and active 10 days ago.
 Checking space and version now

Comment: Version: `Build #PC-211.6693.115 built on April 6, 2021`. Over 200 GB available.

Comment: I have created a bug report for you: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48211

Comment: So, it no longer crashes? Except for colors it looks like it does not crash "immediately"

Comment: I have to be very quick and stop indexing. Then it doesn't immediately crash. I am sorry for not providing this detail, I am learning those as I go

Comment: Closest SO thread seem to be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109313) assuming you have an underlying Java SDK installation maybe try to update it? If that doesn't work the devs will probably have to take a look at it.

Comment: @bad_coder I updated Java runtime. Why is the SDK related? I can try updating that too...

Comment: @Gulzar (I haven't been busy with Java in some time) I mention the JDK because that's what the other thread insistingly refers to. But overall this is well beyond what I'm currently engaged in (whatever that Java version dated 2021 is, try to update it to...) Btw, I just updated to this PyCharm version during the weekend with a fully patched Windows and it's working.

Comment: Let me take one more stab at this -> update the graphic card drivers (symptoms that include mixed-up colors might be related.)

Comment: @bad_coder I am using f.lux for yellowing the screen on purpose (on the Windows side). Are you talking about the whiteness of the background in the Dracula theme?

Comment: @Gulzar good you explained that, in the question you said: "the strange color theme mixup" and I thought that yellowing was part of the problem. But now I notice what you meant was the dark side and top bars with the white editor background. Anyway, if you updated everything, tried clearing temporary files, I think the only chance is the pros at JetBrains bugtracker taking a look.